# Where does "Uniform" in "Uniform central limit theorem" come from?

Tags: stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem

We may all know about the CLT. Today I have seen two articles where the use a new term (to me), that is "Uniform central limit theorem".

1. [A uniform central limit theorem and efficiency for deconvolution estimators](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-6/issue-none/A-uniform-central-limit-theorem-and-efficiency-for-deconvolution-estimators/10.1214/12-EJS757.full)
2. [Empirical Processes in M-Estimation](https://stat.ethz.ch/%7Egeer/cowlas.pdf)

My question is that where the word "uniform" come from? Does it come from "uniform Donsker class"?

Comment: Can you please include the full citations for the articles? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Uniform Central Limit theorems relate to functional extensions of the classic central limit theorem (extending from application to single valued random variables to random functions). They are about the convergence of random *functions*. For instance think about a the Wiener process as a [limit of a random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Wiener_process_as_a_limit_of_random_walk). With a random walk we do not deal with the convergence of a single random value, but with the convergence of an entire function (the entire walk).

Uniform relates to [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence).

See also

- The [Glivenko Cantelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem), which is about a uniform law of large numbers (more specifically the case of convergence of the empirical distribution to the true distribution function). The theorem proves that this convergence is not just pointwise, but also uniform.
- [Donsker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem), which states that a scaled random walk converges uniformly in distribution to a normal distribution.
- There is a whole book written about this topic.

  Dudley, Richard M. [*Uniform central limit theorems.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VxSTAgAAQBAJ&dq=uniform+and+universal+central+limit+theorems) Vol. 142. Cambridge university press, 2014.

Comment: May I ask to understand something? 1. "functional" in "functional extensions" is an adjective, it is not a noun referring to functional in "functional analysis"? 2. Do you mean "random functions"=stochastic process (as you mentioned Wiener and random walk processes)? 3. Is it correct that classical limit theorems are applied to a sequence of random variables, while theorems that you mentioned are applied to stochastic process? 4. Am I correct that both empirical process (a) and empirical measure (b) are extensions of empirical distribution function. Could you help to differentiate (a) and (b)?

Comment: **1** functional refers to 'application to functions' **2** 'random function' refers to stochastic process. **3** yes, it applies to a sequence of stochastic processes **4** I do not understand what you mean by *"empirical process (a) and empirical measure (b)"*.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! For point 4, I think I will make a new question because they are far from the original question (although related, I guess).